# What is the equation of the circle having a radius of square root of 85, through (5,9) and (1,-7)?

Tags: geometry

In solving this problem, I first solved the slope of the perpendicular bisector and I solved the midpoint of the two points. I don't know what to do next. I hope you can help me.

Comment: One way to solve this problem is to assume the centre to be the point $(h,k)$ and then solve for $h$ and $k$ using the fact that both the given points lying on the circle are at a distance of given radius from the centre. You would get two equations.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are two distinct points $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$, either of which may be the center of a satisfying circle.  The easy way to see that is to notice that half the distance from $(1,-7)$ and $(5,9)$ is less than $\sqrt{85}.$  So, imagine the circular arc of radius $\sqrt{85}$ centered at $(1, -7)$ intersecting the circular arc of radius $\sqrt{85}$ centered at $(5,9)$  The two circular arcs will intersect at two distinct points, rather than only one point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find center of a circle given 2 points on the circle and the radius?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773677/how-to-find-center-of-a-circle-given-2-points-on-the-circle-and-the-radius)

Answer (score 4):

hint...let the circle centre be $(a,b)$

You require the line from the centre to the midpoint of the chord to be perpendicular to the chord, i.e $$\frac{b-1}{a-3}=-\frac14$$
and you need the distance from the centre to one of the points given to be equal to the radius, so
$$(a-5)^2+(b-9)^2=85$$

Solve simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Let center to be $(a,b)$. $$(a-5)^2+(b-9)^2=85, (a-1)^2+(b+7)^2=85$$
$$a^2-10a+b^2-18b=-21,a^2-2a+b^2+14b=35$$
Subtracting gives $$8a+32b=56\Rightarrow a+4b=7\Rightarrow a=7-4b$$
$$35=a^2-2a+b^2+14b=49-56b+16b^2-14+8b+b^2+14b=35+17b^2-34b\Rightarrow b^2-2b=0$$
$$b=0\Rightarrow a=7-4b=7; b=2 \Rightarrow a=7-4b=-1$$
$$(x-7)^2+y^2=85 \mathrm{\ or\ } (x+1)^2+(y-2)^2=85$$